# Where do the elements removed by std::remove_if go?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) says that

```
template< class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate >
ForwardIt remove_if( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

> Iterators pointing to an elements between the old and the new ends of
>   the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have
>   unspecified values.

I tried this simple program to find out what they mean by "unspecified values".

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> > ints;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ints.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(i));
    std::remove_if(ints.begin(), ints.end(), 
                  [](const std::shared_ptr<int>& element)
                  {
                      return *element % 7 != 0;
                   });
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << *ints[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0
7
2
3
4
5
6
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

That is something mysterious happens to the data after the 7th element, which causes a segfault.

Interestingly, the possible implementation from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, 
                          UnaryPredicate p)
{
    ForwardIt result = first;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (!p(*first)) {
            *result++ = *first;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Does not produce the segfault.

Is this a bug? Since the iterators should be dereferencable. I am using gcc 4.7.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, in case you aren't aware, you need to remember something very important when you use `std::remove` and `std::remove_if`: they **cannot actually erase elements from the underlying container**. This means that they themselves don't actually *remove* anything.

You need to use something like the *remove/erase* idiom:

```
auto to_erase = std::remove_if(ints.begin(), ints.end(), 
              [](const std::shared_ptr<int>& element)
              {
                  return *element % 7 != 0;
               });
ints.erase(to_erase, ints.end());
```

What happens to "erased" elements is implementation defined. Here is the `gcc` implementation:

```
  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Predicate>
    _ForwardIterator
    remove_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
          _Predicate __pred)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_Mutable_ForwardIteratorConcept<
                  _ForwardIterator>)
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_UnaryPredicateConcept<_Predicate,
        typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::value_type>)
      __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);

      __first = _GLIBCXX_STD_A::find_if(__first, __last, __pred);
      if(__first == __last)
        return __first;
      _ForwardIterator __result = __first;
      ++__first;
      for(; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if(!bool(__pred(*__first)))
          {
            *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
            ++__result;
          }
      return __result;
    }
```

Likely what is causing the segfault is the fact that this implementation calls `_GLIBCXX_MOVE`.

Comment: *"They cannot modify the underlying container"*. That is not true. They do modify the container, in the sense that the elements get re-arranged as a result of the operation. What they cannot do is that reducing the size of the container (i.e the `container.size()` would return same value before and after `std::remove_if`, only some elements (which are removed by the operations) are *unspecified* as per the C++ Standard).

Comment: @Nawaz Poor wording on my part. I've reworded my answer.

Comment: C++ standard algorithms do not apply to **containers**. They apply to **sequences**. Containers are one source of sequences, but not the only one.

Comment: *Gotcha* - use `remove_if` carefully with `erase`. If you forget to use ranged erase from this vector, ie. `v.erase(remove_if(...), v.end())`, and just type `v.erase(remove_if(...))` - this will only erase the first element. You will end up with invalid `shared_ptr`s after that.

Answer (score 7):

The iterators may be dereferenceable but the shared pointers might not be. You should check for nullness before dereferencing a shared pointer with an unspecified value.

Comment: But what do you think happened to the data? If the implementation is so simple. Would using move semantics inside their implementation cause such behaviour?

Comment: I haven't even thought about what "happened to the data". The values of the shared pointer are not part of the contract so I simply don't care about them. It is possible that the members of the range are moved and this results in empty shared pointers, or possibly an "old fashioned" in-place destruct and copy construct instead of assignment. You should be able to find the source code of `std::remove_if` on your system (as it is a template) to verify this.

Answer (score 5):

A C++11 compiler will use move semantics if possible to move the elements that are not 'removed' by `std::remove_if`.  Moving a shared_ptr leaves the original shared_ptr object empty (it no longer owns a pointer) - calling `get()` on that original shared_ptr will return a null pointer.

Therefore if you dereference that shared_ptr, you'll get a null pointer dereference.

So, in summary, while the iterator is still dereferenceable, the shared_ptr might not be.